# Windows 8 Exchange 2007 Activesync policies

Tags: windows, exchange-2007, activesync

I've looked all over for an answer to my issue, but the only articles I can find refer to Exchange 2010 NOT Exchange 2007. Here's my issue.

I have a Windows 8 workstation connecting to my Exchange 2007 server. When I connect the exchange account it makes me enforce password policies on the workstation. I have check the two ActiveSync policies I have on the Exchange server - one for provisionable devices and one for non-provisionable. Both have password requirements completely turned off. Yet Windows 8 still makes me enforce a password policy. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Turned out I didn't have the correct ActiveSync policy applied to my mailbox. To do this I went to Recipient Configuration > Mailbox > Right clicked my mailbox choose properties > Mailbox Features tab > highlight Exchange ActiveSync click properties > Then browse and apply the correct policy.

By the way it only worked when I applied a policy that had True for Non-Provisionable Devices Allowed.